# Export variable named ranges on separate worksheets to one pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, named-ranges

I am self taught so there is a lot of trial and error in my programming, however, depending on a cell value I put the name of a range in to a cell (could be 1 name, could be 30) I named PRINTBOX using &, formula. This works fine on a single worksheet, but I cant get it to work on multiple worksheets in the same workbook. This is my code:-

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Range("PRINTBOX").Value).ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas :=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating
```

I have tried activating all associated worksheets, but all I print out is the print range of that worksheet. I have tried setting the print range to the named range but alas I am getting nowhere - please help

Steve

Comment: Could you explain *could be 1 name, could be 30*? If this code works for one range, you should add another worksheet and copy all ranges to it and use the same line of code on the new worksheet. Add more detail to your post to get a decent answer.

Comment: Hi, there are  30 ranges on 30 one worksheet, These range names are added to a single cell for  printing to one pdf. This works fine, but if I was to do the same for ranges from different worksheets, It fails to work - thanks